# How to use a GIT post hook to apply the changes to a different repository

Tags: git, hook, repository

I have this situation:

**Repository A** contains some kind of a **framework** (e.g. CakePHP with a basic setup and some common controllers).

**Repository B** contains a **project, based on Repository A**, with additional files, and some changes/additions in the files coming from the framework.

Unfortunately, structure can't be changed so that A is a separate subfolder in the B project (in the controllers folder are the common controllers from the framework, plus the additional ones).

I want to achieve the following:

**After pushing** some changes to the framework (A), I want those **changes being applied to different repositories** (B). A and B are setup as shared bare repositories on a server.

As I understand it, `post-receive` (or `post-commit`?) hooks could handle that, but I have no idea how it's done. I think the hook should create a patch file from the last change, and somehow apply this to several other repositories.

**Does someone have an example for that?**

(another approach was, to use one repository for all projects based on that framework, and each project being a branch, but this didn't look very clean and I didn't like the idea of putting all projects into just one big clump).

Comment: You should make the framework ("`A`") a part of all the projects that use it (use *git submodule* or *git subtree*).  Then write a script that will update the submodule/subtree in each project that uses it.  This way, you can also control exactly which version of `A` is used in each of the projects (that is actually the problem you're solving here, not the technicality of including the framework).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a patch from `--bare` repo `A` (on some server) to `B` (and `C`, `D`, `E`...), the main problem is figuring this out: "which versions of `A` do `B`, `C`, `D`, ... have, and which ones should they have?"

For instance, suppose someone working on `A` did:

```
git push origin master:experiment_for_joe devel:featureX
```

to take stuff he had on his local `master` branch and give it to Joe (before moving it around somehow in his own repo, perhaps) and to take stuff he had on his `devel` branch and name it `featureX` on the server.

Do some version(s) of experiment_for_joe and/or featureX go to `B`?  Or maybe only to `D`?

Let's say the answer to that is "no, never, only whatever gets into `deploy` goes out".  Easy enough, but now the other half of the question: what if `B` had the latest and greatest before someone added three commits to `deploy`, but for some reason, `C` was seven commits behind?  What if the version on `D` does not match *any* version in repo `A`?

Assuming you can resolve all these questions, and get down to something like this:

```
devel on A is now the latest
B has $on_B which is definitely in A
C has $on_C which is definitely in A
```

(and so on), then—assuming `B`, `C`, etc., are all repos and you want all the intermediate commits to show up (if not, you can get one big patch instead):

```
git format-patch $on_B..devel
```

gets you the series of patches needed to bring `B` in sync, and:

```
git format-patch $on_C..devel
```

gets you the series of patches needed to bring `C` in sync, and so on.  (These may need massaging to apply properly, if the target repos "don't really match".)

(If they're not repos, use `git diff $on_B devel`, or `git diff-tree` and/or some underlying plumbing bits, to get a direct mapping of "how to change what's on `B` to what's in `devel`".  However, if anything goes wrong here, the two can get out of sync and it will be hard to recover.  If `B`, `C`, etc, *are* repos, you have more chance of figuring out what you need to do to recover.)